# Compiling a String into an Exp with TemplateHaskell

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

I'm looking for a way to compile a string of a valid Haskell expression code into a TH `Exp`.

E.g., if there existed an appropriate function, I'd expect it to behave the following way:

```
> $(theFunctionImLookingFor "\a -> a + 1") 2
3
```

I've already looked for the implementation of `quoteExp :: String -> Q Exp` for the underlying [`QuasiQuoter`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.8.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH-Quote.html) of `[e|..|]`, but it seems to be magic and there is none.

Comment: It can be done, but only on strings known at compile time.  Given that constraint, why not just use a quasiquote?

Comment: Since we're talking about TemplateHaskell, of course it's compile time. I need this for an implementation of a custom QuasiQuoter. One of its jobs is to just store the result of the quoted Haskell expression.

Comment: Got it, makes more sense.  I have one more question though....  Could you just wrap the builtin expression quasiquoter, just pass quoteExp through with the extra (unsafe, I am guessing) IO to log the result?  Or are there enough other changes to how the builtin quoteExp works to warrent a rewrite?

Comment: As mentioned, I couldn't find this "built in" quoteExp. It seems like it's magic.

Comment: The function you are looking for is `Language.Haskell.Meta.Parse.parseExp` in `haskell-src-meta`.

Comment: @user2407038 That's it! Thanks! If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function you are looking for is [`parseExp`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-exts-1.23.1/docs/Language-Haskell-Exts-Parser.html#v:parseExp) from the [`Language.Haskell.Meta.Parse` module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-exts-1.23.1/docs/Language-Haskell-Exts-Parser.html) in the [`haskell-src-meta` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-exts).